# RecordsetClone.RecordCount only counts records visible - not those you can scroll to

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm using `RecordsetClone.RecordCount` to show the number of records in a subform.

Problem is, it's only counting those that fit within the borders of the subform when the form loads; any records in the subform that you'd need to scroll down to see are not counted.

Is this the normal behaviour of `RecordsetClone.RecordCount`? Is there another method that will count all records in my subform including those below the bottom border?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nevermind. Found out that to ensure an accurate `RecordCount` you should use `MoveLast` before doing the `RecordCount`. Context and code below to anyone who has the same problem:

**Context**:

I've designed a search tool using the main form to hold all the search filters (text boxes) and the "Search" command button. The results of the search are displayed on subform below the search filters. I was wanting to use `RecordCount` to pass the number results returned in the search to a text box on the main form called **txtResultsNum**.

I was using the following code to achieve this:

```vb
Dim ResultNum As String

ResultNum = Trim(Me.MySubForm.Form.RecordsetClone.RecordCount)

Me.txtResultNum.ControlSource = "=""("" & " & ResultNum & " &"")"""
```

Unfortunately this (for me at least) would only count to the number of records that could be displayed in the subform before the user had to scroll down, so was giving an inaccurate count of all the records.

To get an accurate count use `MoveLast` before doing the `RecordCount`:

```vb
Dim ResultNum As String

Dim rs As Recordset

    Set rs = Me.MySubForm.Form.Recordset

        rs.MoveLast

        ResultNum = rs.RecordCount

        Me.txtResultNum.ControlSource = "=""("" & " & ResultNum & " &"")"""

        rs.MoveFirst

    Set rs = Nothing
```

Note I've also used `MoveFirst` at the end; this is because 'MoveLast` will automatically move focus to the last record in the subform, which isn't what I wanted (I'd prefer the user sees the first record and works their way down).